# SQL Server version of Oracle's ADD_MONTHS()

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date-arithmetic

In Oracle, you can use ADD_Months to add months on the fly in the sql statement. What is the MS SQL version.

Oracle Example

```
Select TestDate, 
       TestFrequency,
        ADD_MONTHS(TestDate, TestFrequency) AS FutureTestDate 
  FROM Tests
```

Source : [java's website](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Date-Timezone/ADDMONTHSScheduleanumberofmonthsafterthecurrentdate.htm)

Comment: BTW, the product name is "SQL Server"

Comment: the problem is that "MSSQL" is easily confused with "MySQL". Also, most people looking for questions about SQL Server will naturally not go searching for the string "MSSQL". Besides, I've never heard of any other product calling itself "a SQL server".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its `DATEADD(MONTH, TestFrequency, TestDate)` to add `TestFrequency` number of months to the date field `TestDate`.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server's TSQL equivalent to [Oracle's PLSQL ADD_MONTHS function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php) is [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
SELECT TestDate, 
       TestFrequency,
       DATEADD(mm, TestFrequency, TestDate)
  FROM TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how Oracles Add_Months works, but MS Sql has this:

```
   Declare @NumMonthsToAdd TinyInt Set @NumMonthsToAdd  = 6
   Declare @aDate DateTime Set @aDate = '12 Jan 2010'
   Select DateAdd(month, @numMonthstoAdd, @aDate)
      -- above will generate datetime of '12 July 2010'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ADD_MONTHS]
(
    @inDate SMALLDATETIME,
    @inFrequency INT

)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(MONTH, @inFrequency, @inDate)
END


-- TO Call : 
-- SELECT dbo.ADD_MONTHS(3,getdate()) AS newDate
```