# Filtering Records in SQL Server using date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I need to select all the records which are not older than 18 months. I wrote this query for SQL Server. But it don't seem to work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company, 
        Name,
        PhoneNumber,
FROM        Request
WHERE       Company  LIKE @Company
AND     RequestDate >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -18)
```

Comment: Should have looked here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208042/sql-server-version-of-oracles-add-months

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company, Name, PhoneNumber, 
FROM Request WHERE Company LIKE @Company 
AND RequestDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -18, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks @msmucker0527 for the quick reply. It works fine. Sad that I cannot select it as the answer for another 10 mins.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company,  
        Name, 
        PhoneNumber, 
FROM        Request 
WHERE       Company  LIKE @Company 
AND     datediff(mm, RequestDate, getdate()) <= 18
```

Use the [`DATEDIFF` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for this.  The above query should get you your desired results.

Comment: -1. Forces a table scan by calculating on field value. BAD practice. It is always better to comapre to a precalculated start date. Perforamnce of that sucks - this is abuse of SQL.

Comment: @TomTom Great point, and thank you for the tip.  I'd change my answer to reflect, but msmucher0527 has that answer, and it looks like the OP will accept his answer.  Nevertheless, you are right and thank you for the reminder.